# Incorrect model item passed into dictionary when rendering view from another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I logged in user visits their profile vial `Manage` -> `Index.cshtml`, I want to display to them all the orders made through the organisation which they belong to.

These orders are usually displayed in an organisation's `Details.cshtml` with

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Order", new { org = Model });}
```

Where `model` contains a `ViewOrganisationViewModel`, where all the orders are stored.

This works perfectly.

Now when I want to do the same for a logged in user, I tried:

#### Manage Index.html

```
@{Html.RenderAction("MyIndex", "Order");}
```

#### OrderController.cs

Here I added the `MyIndex` method, which first gets the user's `OrganisationId` in order to build the correct `ViewOrganisationViewModel`. This entire method runs without error.

```
public ActionResult Index(ViewOrganisationViewModel org)
{
    return PartialView(org.Orders);
}

public ActionResult MyIndex()
{
    Models.ApplicationUser user =
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()
            .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
            .FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());

    var organisationManager = new OrganisationManager();
    var org = organisationManager.Select(user.OrganisationId);

    return View("Index", org);
}
```

Now when the applications tries to return to `Index(ViewOrganisationViewMode org)`, I get:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'AuroraWeb.ViewOrganisationViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[AuroraWeb.ViewOrderViewModel]'.

Why is it doing this? The method does **not** expect an `IEnumerable` of the ViewModel, so am I missing something here?

I also tried changing the `return` line in `MyIndex` to

```
return Index(org);
```

But it then complains that there is no `MyIndex.cshtml` view (Which there isn't because I only need to return the `Index` view..)

I also tried

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { org = org });
```

but got

> Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.

Please let me know if I can provide any extra details.

Comment: Your `Index.cshtml` view has `@model IEnumerable<AuroraWeb.ViewOrderViewModel>`  but your passing it a single `ViewOrganisationViewModel`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you. I was thinking of it in terms of returning the controller action but I guess it just returns the `Index` view in `OrderController` directly

Comment: I'm guessing that you want `return View("Index", org.Orders);` (i.e as per the model/code in the `Index()` method)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yup, that did it. Should I close this question or do you wan to add an answer??

Comment: I already closed it :)